# I am writing c++ code to implement Queue using pointer array.Memory allocation is not happening correctly.Any suggestion?

Tags: c++

This is my code for queue using pointer array.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Queue>

using namespace std;

#define size 2

class Queue{  
public:      
    int f;
    int r;
    int* arr;
public:
    Queue(){
        arr = new int [size];
        int f, r = -1;
    }

    int isEmpty(){
        if(r == -1 && f == -1){
            cout<<"Queue underflow";
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int isFull(){
        if(r == size - 1){
            cout<<"Queue overflow";
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void enqueue(int val){
        if( isFull()){
            cout << "Cannot push element in Queue";
        }
        else{
            arr[r] = val;
            r++;
            cout << "The value in Queue is" << " " << val << endl;
        }
    }

    int dequeue(){
        int a = -1;
        if( isEmpty()){
            cout << "Cannot pop element from Queue";
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            a = arr[f]; 
            f++;
            return a;
        }
    } 
};

int main(){
    Queue q;
    q.f = q.r = 0;
    q.enqueue(1);
    q.enqueue(2);
    q.enqueue(3);
    cout << "Dequeuing element is" << q.dequeue() << endl;
    cout << "Dequeuing element is" << q.dequeue() << endl;
    cout << "Dequeuing element is" << q.dequeue() << endl;
    cout << "Dequeuing element is" << q.dequeue() << endl;
    if( q.isEmpty()){
        cout << "Queue is empty";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output

```
The value in Queue is 1
Queue overflow The value in Queue is 2
The value in Queue is 3
Dequeuing element is1
Dequeuing element is2
Dequeuing element is3
Dequeuing element is563
```

Though I have set size as 2 still after printing one it says 'Queue Overflow' and then print the data also when I dequeue 4th element (though there is no forth element) it prints the line with absurd numbers.

Comment: What's with the random \\s in the code?

Comment: Also `int f, r=-1;` in the `Queue` constructor doesn't assign initial values to `Queue::f` and `Queue::r` the class member variables, it creates new variables whose scope is the constructor itself. It also only assigns `-1` to `r`--is that what you wanted to do, or did you mean to set both `f` and `r` to `-1`?

Comment: I have put \\ because it was not accepting my code without it

Comment: @NathanPierson I wanted to assign -1 to both f and r

Comment: Question: When does `isFull` return a value other than `0`? Same applies for `isEmpty`

Comment: @NathanPierson yes it will return 0 when both the conditions get false

Comment: I asked when it will return a value _other than_ `0`. Yes, it returns `0` when both conditions are false. It also returns `0` every other time, no matter what.

Comment: @NathanPierson I guess I should add a line saying `return 1` when the condition in `isfull` and `isEmpty` get true

Answer (score 0):

As Nathan Pierson correctly pointed out, your functions `isFull` and `isEmpty` always return 0, which gets implicitly converted to false in an if statement, hence your checks in `enqueue` and `dequeue` are not working and the functions are always executed. Additionally, I would like to point out a few other things:

1. Please don't use preprocessor directive to define a size variable, use `constexpr` instead. (`constexpr int size = 2;`). The name you have chosen (size) is very dangerous, most of the STL containers have a method also called size. Your preprocessor directive would then substitute function call with `2`, breaking compilation.
2. You have two member variables in your Queue class: `r` and `f`. What do they mean? You check them in your methods `isFull` and `isEmpty` so I guess they are quite important. Please use descriptive names for variables (for example use front and back)
3. Your methods `isFull` and `isEmpty` return int to indicate true or false values. In C++ there is a special type designed to indicate true or false: `bool`. Please use it instead of int.